# USB drive mounts but user can't write to drive?

Tags: usb, mount

I've got a bare bones Ubuntu 10.04 set up (xorg, openbox, usbmount). My (vfat32) stick drive mounts, and I can see what is in the one directory on the drive, but I can't write to the drive unless I use sudo. I tried the obvious step of attempting to change permissions on the drive

```
keith@quiet:~$ sudo chmod -R 777 /media/usb0
[sudo] password for keith: 
keith@quiet:~$ ls /media/usb0
stuff
keith@quiet:~$ touch /media/usb0/readme.txt
touch: cannot touch `/media/usb0/readme.txt': Permission denied
```

Comment: Please notice that Ubuntu 10.04 passed end of life in April 2015 and it receives no security updates. So it should not be connected to the internet. Also please notice that if you want support here at AskUbuntu, you should ask about current versions of Ubuntu and Ubuntu community flavours. For example, current versions of Lubuntu and Xubuntu work well with old hardware (where there may be problems with current versions of Ubuntu).

Comment: Try: sudo chown user:user /media/usb0 , replace << user >> with your username and group

Answer (score -1):

I can be that the filesystem is incorrect. I had this before. you should mount the usb including a filesystem:
`mount -t vfat /dev/USB /media/usb0`
or
`mount -t vfat /dev/USB /media/usb0 -o uid=YOURID,gid=YOURID`
when the system does not detect the filesystem it will say permission denied because it can't write to it and it just assumes that you don't have permission.

Answer (score -2):

Anyway, to add an entry into fstab it would go something like this:

Open **Terminal**

Type **sudo mkdir /media/usbstick**

Type **gksu gedit /etc/fstab**

Add an entry that looks like this:

```
UUID=3C52-C8C5 /media/usbstick vfat user,umask=000,utf8,flush,noauto 0 0
```

The "user" and "noauto" will allow the user to mount the device automatically when inserted.

The "umask=000" will allow read / write access to everyone.

When you're done, save fstab, exit gedit, and back in the Terminal type:

**sudo mount -a**

Then insert the stick and find out if I'm full of hooey